# Convert a single column dataframe into multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R that looks like the data created with this code (only much longer)

```
vec <- c("Status:", "Pass", "Date:", "08/11/2018")
df <- data.frame(Variables = vec)
```

I want a dataframe with the column headings being the values ending in a colon with the values being the row below. So the above would look like this

```
Status  | Date
Pass   |  08/11/2018
```

How can this be done? I don't even know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a logical vector to recycle

```
i1 <- c(FALSE, TRUE)
d1 <- as.data.frame.list(vec[i1])
names(d1) <- sub(":", "", vec[!i1])
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you